# wordpress General Settings pre save hook

Tags: wordpress

is there any way to detect if wp General Settings updated (wp-admin/options-general.php page) and do some staff after Save Changes?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same question the 24.september 2020.

This is the solution I arrived at, but I only wanted to register the change to the site language:

```
add_filter( 'pre_update_option_WPLANG', function( $new_value, $old_value ) {
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
$msg = 'oldvalue: ' . $old_value . "\n\n new value: " . $new_value . "\n\n user: " . (string) $current_user->user_email ;
  wp_mail( 'myemail@myemail.com', 'SOMEONE CHANGED LANGUAGE OF [domainname]', $msg );

  return $new_value;

}, 10, 2);
```

So basically using the **pre_update_option_{$option}** filter.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_update_option_option/